# How to properly project and plot raster in R

Tags: r, gis, r-raster

I have a raster in an equal area Behrmann projection and I would like to project it to the Mollweide projection and plot.

When I do this with the following code, however, the plotting doesn't seem right, as the map extends to the sides, and there are outlines of various landmasses where I wouldn't expect them.Also, the map extends beyond the plot window.

Can anyone please help me get this to plot nicely?

Thanks!

The data file used can be downloaded from [this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34644229/sst.tif).

Here is the code I have so far:

```
require(rgdal)
require(maptools)
require(raster)

data(wrld_simpl)

mollCRS <- CRS('+proj=moll')
behrmannCRS <- CRS('+proj=cea +lat_ts=30')

sst <- raster("~/Dropbox/Public/sst.tif", crs=behrmannCRS)

sst_moll <- projectRaster(sst, crs=mollCRS)
wrld <- spTransform(wrld_simpl, mollCRS)

plot(sst_moll)
plot(wrld, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Difficulties-with-Eckert-IV-Mollweide-projection-of-RasterLayer-with-global-extent-td7580864.html) thread, I think it deals with the same problem.

Comment: Thank you! Although the problem described does sound identical, the suggested fix does not change anything in my case.

Answer (score 6):

Alright, since the example at [this](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Difficulties-with-Eckert-IV-Mollweide-projection-of-RasterLayer-with-global-extent-td7580864.html) page seems to work, I tried to mimic it as much as possible. I think problems arise because the far left and far right side of the raster image overlap. Cropping and an intermediate reprojection to Lat-Lon as in the example seem to solve your problem.

Perhaps this workaround can be a basis for a more elegant solution that directly addresses the problem, as it is not benificial to reproject a raster twice.

```
# packages
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(raster)

# define projections
mollCRS <- CRS('+proj=moll')
behrmannCRS <- CRS('+proj=cea +lat_ts=30')

# read data
data(wrld_simpl)
sst <- raster("~/Downloads/sst.tif", crs=behrmannCRS)

# crop sst to extent of world to avoid overlap on the seam
world_ext = projectExtent(wrld_simpl, crs = behrmannCRS)
sst_crop = crop(x = sst, y=world_ext, snap='in')

# convert sst to longlat (similar to test file)
# somehow this gets rid of the unwanted pixels outside the ellipse
sst_longlat = projectRaster(sst_crop, crs = ('+proj=longlat'))

# then convert to mollweide
sst_moll <- projectRaster(sst_longlat, crs=mollCRS, over=T)
wrld <- spTransform(wrld_simpl, mollCRS)

# plot results
plot(sst_moll)
plot(wrld, add=TRUE)
```

[image]