# How to plot global rasters with tmap in Robinson projection without duplicated areas?

Tags: r, raster, rgdal, tmap, r-stars

I've been plotting some global rasters lately using mainly raster and tmap. I'd like to plot the maps in Robinson projection instead of lat-lon. Simple projection to Robinson however duplicates some areas on the edges of the map as you can see from the figures below (Alaska, Siberia, NZ).

Previously, I found a workaround with PROJ.4 code parameter "+over" as outlined in [here](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Difficulties-with-Eckert-IV-Mollweide-projection-of-RasterLayer-with-global-extent-td7580864.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535047/how-to-properly-project-and-plot-raster-in-r).

With the latest changes to rgdal using GDAL > 3 and PROJ >= 6, this workaround seems to be obsolete. Has anyone found a new way on how to plot global rasters in Robinson/Eckert IV/Mollweide without duplicated areas?

I'm running R 4.0.1, tmap 3.1, stars 0.4-3, raster 3.3-7, rgdal 1.5-12, sp 1.4-2, GDAL 3.1.1 and PROJ 6.3.1 on a macOS Catalina 10.15.4

```
require(stars)
require(raster)
require(tmap)
require(dplyr)

# data
worldclim_prec = getData(name = "worldclim", var = "prec", res = 10)
jan_prec <- worldclim_prec$prec1

# to Robinson and plot - projection outputs a warning
jp_rob <- jan_prec %>%
  projectRaster(crs = "+proj=robin +over")
tm_shape(jp_rob) + tm_raster(style = "fisher")
```

```
Warning messages:
1: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO") :
  Discarded ellps WGS 84 in CRS definition: +proj=robin +over
2: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO") :
  Discarded datum WGS_1984 in CRS definition
```

[image]

I tried to do the same with stars instead of raster but no resolution was found, supposedly since tmap uses stars since version 3.0.

```
# new grid for warping stars objects
newgrid <- st_as_stars(jan_prec) %>%
  st_transform("+proj=robin +over") %>%
  st_bbox() %>%
  st_as_stars()

# to stars object - projection outputs no warning
jp_rob_stars <- st_as_stars(jan_prec) %>%
  st_warp(newgrid)

tm_shape(jp_rob_stars) + tm_raster(style = "fisher")
```

Thanks for any insights - hoping someone else is thinking about this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `raster` you can do

```
library(raster)
prec <- getData(name = "worldclim", var = "prec", res = 10)[[1]]
crs <- "+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m"
rrob <- projectRaster(prec, crs=crs)
```

Create a mask

```
library(geosphere)
e <- as(extent(prec), "SpatialPolygons")
crs(e) <- crs(prec)
e <- makePoly(e)  # add additional vertices
re <- spTransform(e, crs)
```

And use it

```
mrob <- mask(rrob, re)
```

The new package `terra` has a `mask` argument for that (you need version >= 0.8.3 for this, [available from github](https://github.com/rspatial/terra))

```
prec <- getData(name = "worldclim", var = "prec", res = 10)[[1]]
jp <- rast(prec$prec1) 
jp <- jp * 1 # to deal with NAs in this datasaet
rob <- project(jp, crs, mask=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Robert for your answer; much appreciated! Solution via masking works very well. Perhaps I should consider migrating to terra as well if it's going to replace raster at some point.